# Alternatives to DIA - a floss diagram drawing software for linux

Tags: linux, open-source, drawing

I've been using [DIA](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia) for a long time for casual and professional drawings however it has been discontinued for a long time now.

The program should:

- Allow to draw simple flowcharts, UML and other diagrams
- Be available on GNU/Linux
- Have a FLOSS license

The only libre alternative I could find was libre office draw which is not to my liking.
Are there any libre, light diagram drawing software on linux?

Prime use-case to illustrate program flow.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Must it absolutely be FLOSS, or would [tag:gratis] be enough? I have the perfect tool fro you. It's Java, but I am not sure if you may edit the source. It doesn't cost, though

Comment: "program flow" as in flowchart, or as in Message Sequence Chart?

Comment: @Mawg as in flow chart and yes I'm only interested in floss alternatives. There really isn't much to add to the question: flowchart drawing program that is FLOSS on linux. So far I've only found Dia which has been amazing and works but discontinued for almost a decade now or libreoffice draw which is very much inferior to even discontinued Dia in my opinion.

Comment: Did you have a look at plantuml or graphviz dot ?

Comment: @albert I heartily endorse both of them. The big advantage for me is that I can describe my diagram in ASCII text and have it generated. The ASCII text is usually produced from a Python script which massages other data,  such as debug output from test runs, which I use for drawing Message Sequence Charts, etc. If [tag:grais] were ok, I would also recommend [Yed](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) as being similar to Dia, but superior.

Comment: @mawg the grais link point to no results, did you mean something different? For the Message Sequence Charts there is, of course, also the 'mscgen' program.

Comment: lolx Typo  "grais" --> [tag:gratis]

Comment: There are two "mscgen" apps, (at least for Windows). [This one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msc-generator/) is more powerful and the developer is extremely friendly & helpful and responds quickly to emails

Comment: Frankly I don't understand the obsession with getting a software that has to be built within the last year or so. A reason for something not receiving updates could be that it's seen as mature enough by the authors. Alternatively with FLOSS it could be a lack of motivation or a lack of time or both (or a variety of other reasons). Commercial software vendors will often just recompile software with few to no changes, just in order to make it seem like progress is happening. The difference is that with FLOSS that's pointless, because anyone can see the changes in the source (or not).

Comment: @0xC0000022L oh I'm not stopping to use DIA - I love it; but since it's discontinued I'm afraid it will stop working at some point so I'd rather prepare to switch just by playing around once in a while rather than being dropped dead in time of need.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now that's of course a different story then. Apologies for jumping to conclusions there. As FLOSS developer myself I can tell you that the bureaucracy is often eating up more time than developing stuff. So if you have time to donate, I'm sure the DIA dev(s) will appreciate it. This could be something as simple as tending to support requests or others tasks that are necessary in any FLOSS project, but have to be deducted from the development time available.

Answer (score 1):

How about online solution that works from browser? I use this: https://www.draw.io/. Try it, maybe fits your needs

Comment: There are a bunch of these, but the OP seems fixed on FLOSS

Comment: I've used draw.io before and while I like it, my initial question is for linux-native and floss software.

Answer (score 1):

### Use GraphViz!

The best solution I know and often use are the programs in the GraphViz collection. GraphViz

- Can draw any graphs (includes flowcharts, UML and other diagrams)
- Is available under GNU/Linux (package name: graphviz)
- Has a FLOSS licence ([Common public licence 1.0](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:CPLv1.0))

Similar to LaTeX, instead of drawing by hand you type what you need. The program compiles your file and distributes the nodes automatically. There are even more programs for different arrangements!

If you want to edit the structure later: Export it as an svg and edit the nodes with a vector graphics program like Inkscape.

Don't worry about the learning curve! The language/format is really very simple. It takes as with any other new program about one hour to learn. Here is a short example:

```
Animal [
    label = "{Animal|+ name : string\l+ age : int\l|+ die() : void\l}"
]
```

compiles to

[image: uml class]

Here is a [**simple tutorial**](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php) on creating UML diagrams and since GraphViz is a general graph layout generating software have a look at [this introduction](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7275) which gives an even more detailed explanation.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Very cool but `dot` notation seems to have quite a learning curve and not as flexible as DIA, at least when being created without automation. Though it seems like it's worth investing some time learning the ropes.